# android: making edittext not editable and then make it back editable again

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make `edittext_2` not editable if `edittext_1` is empty, but  if `edittext_1` is not empty I want `edittext_2` to be editable.

I tried this code:

```
if (edittext_1.getText().toString().equals(""))
{ 
    edittext_2.setEnabled(false);
}
else
{
    edittext_2.setEnabled(true);
}
```

In the beginning the code works fine it makes `edittext_2` not editable, but when I enter a value in `edittext_1`,  `edittext_2` still not editable.

Comment: Where are you using this condition, i mean in onCreate method or in button click etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `edittext_1` on `TextWatcher()`.

Try this

```
edittext_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                edittext_2.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                edittext_2.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if (edittext_1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{ 
  edittext_2.setEnabled(false);
  edittext_2.setFocusable(false);

}
else
{
 edittext_2.setEnabled(true);
 edittext_2.setFocusable(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editText2.setEnabled(false);
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (!editText1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                editText2.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                editText2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have initialized will work for first time but when you make some changes in the `edittext_1`, you should again enable the `edittext_2`.Add the following code also,

```
edittext_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               if (edittext_1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                 { 
                   edittext_2.setEnabled(false);
                 }
               else
                 {
                 edittext_2.setEnabled(true);

                 }
              }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```